# Looping through DataGridView columns, the first column is not recognized

Tags: c#, .net, csv, datagridview, computer-science

Using a `foreach` loop, I'm going through all the columns inside my `datagridview`. The `datagridview` I have is being filled from a CSV file.

It shows all the data correctly.

This is the foreach loop:

```
foreach (DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col in dgviewPreview.Columns)
{
   if (col.Name.Equals("FirstColumn"))
      MessageBox.Show(col.Name);
}
```

This is a sample of my CSV file that the program reads:

[image]

If I remove the

> if (col.Name.Equals("FirstColumn"))

Line from my foreach loop, all the columns are displayed. Even when I use any other column name other than FirstColumn in my condition (e.g. "Company Name", "Email"), the message box is correctly show. But the first column (no matter which file I'm loading into the Gridview or what the name of the column is) is never recognized by the if statement. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Has anyone had the same problem?

**Update**: Screen shot of my current columns at runtime.
[image]

**Update 2**: 
[This](https://www.mediafire.com/?h3tqgvn98dlimwj) is a link to the csv file I'm using.

Comment: @GrantWinney Yes I have done that. I updated my post with a screen shot of what I asked. Please take a look!

Comment: Did you try with Col Index? I mean from 0 to Col Count - 1?

Comment: @Nilesh yes I did. It works and recognizes the 0 index. But when I change it back to col.Name it does not recognize it. Even though all other columns are recognized. It can be something very simple that I am missing. I have tried trimming the string as well to no avail.

Comment: Gimme some time, I will reach home and try this out, cause I do not have access to VS right now. I will follow this post...

Comment: @GrantWinney I uploaded the sample csv file I'm using. But the parser's code is quite big. You think there's an invisible character that is making it all go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a case in-sensitive comparison like this?:

```
if(String.Compare(col.Name, "firstcolumn", true) == 0) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some strange reason, the problem was solved when I copied the entire contents of the CSV file to new file (just a  `ctrl+A/ctrl+V`) and it seems to be working now. I never understood the issue but for now it is solved.